# CocoaPods: Adding half dependency of AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I have made my own private Cocoapods. At some point it had to access the network, so I added the dependency of `AFNetworking` in my Cocoapods as following

```
s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'
```

AFNetworking has 5 `subspecs` which are following:

'`Reachability', 'Serialization', 'Security', 'NSURLSession' 'UIKit'`.

I do not need the UIKit. How can add only other four subspecs as dependancy.

Following is my Pod File:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name             = 'MyPrivatePod'
    s.version          = '0.1.6'
    s.summary          = 'MyPrivatePod is an SDK used for processing a heavy task in the project.'
    
    s.description      = "MyPrivatePod provides extensive features while doing private processing. This is private pod and desription is private to"
    
    s.homepage         = 'https://path/to/my/priavate/pod/git/_git/MyPrivatePodPodSpecs_iOS'
    s.license          = { :type => 'Private', :file => 'LICENSE' }
    s.author           = { 'asifhabib' => 'asif.habib11@gmail.com' }
    s.source           = { :git => 'https://path/to/my/priavate/pod/git/_git/MyPrivatePodPodSpecs_iOS', :tag => s.version.to_s }
    
    s.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'
    
    s.source_files = 'MyPrivatePod/Classes/**/*.{h,m,swift}'
    s.resources = 'MyPrivatePod/Classes/**/*.{storyboard,xib,xcassets}'
    
    s.resource_bundles = {
        'MyPrivatePod' => ['MyPrivatePod/Classes/**/*.{storyboard,xib,xcassets}']
    }
    s.info_plist = { 'CFBundleIdentifier' => 'com.cph.MyPrivatePod' }
    
    s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER': 'com.cph.MyPrivatePod' }
    
    s.dependency 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.2.0'
    s.dependency 'Toast-Swift', '~> 5.0.1'
    s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'
    
    s.swift_version = "4.2"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it like this in your podspec file.

```
 s.dependency 'AFNetworking/Serialization'
 s.dependency 'AFNetworking/Security'
 s.dependency 'AFNetworking/Reachability'
```

**OR** if you want to specify the version

```
s.dependency 'AFNetworking/Serialization',   '~> 3.2.1'
s.dependency 'AFNetworking/Security',        '~> 3.2.1'
s.dependency 'AFNetworking/Reachability',    '~> 3.2.1'
```

https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec